# Repeat Active Filter After Userform Entry

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a macro that sorts clients based off of "Contact Dates", "Deposits", and "Credit". Say I select to sort by "Contact Date" and then I add a new client to my list, how would can I have the **active** sort re-run after I have entered a new client from my user form?

> Userform I use to add client data

[image: UserForm I use to enter Data]

> Filter Options

[image: Filter Options]

Here is my code:

> Credit Balance Sort

```
Sub creditbalance()

    Dim w As Long, lr As Long, wss As Variant

    wss = Array("contactunder")


    For w = LBound(wss) To UBound(wss)
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wss(w))
            lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row, _
                                 .Cells(.Rows.Count, "da").End(xlUp).Row)
            With .Range(.Cells(10, "a"), .Cells(lr, "da"))
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(97), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End With
        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

> Contact Date Sort

```
Sub contactdate()
    Dim w As Long, lr As Long, wss As Variant

    wss = Array("contactunder")


    For w = LBound(wss) To UBound(wss)
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wss(w))
            lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row, _
                                 .Cells(.Rows.Count, "da").End(xlUp).Row)
            With .Range(.Cells(10, "a"), .Cells(lr, "da"))
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End With
        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

> Deposit Balance Sort

```
Sub depositbalance()
    Dim w As Long, lr As Long, wss As Variant

    wss = Array("contactunder")


    For w = LBound(wss) To UBound(wss)
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wss(w))
            lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row, _
                                 .Cells(.Rows.Count, "da").End(xlUp).Row)
            With .Range(.Cells(10, "a"), .Cells(lr, "da"))
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(68), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End With
        End With
    Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `.Sort.Apply`? That said your life would be much easier if you worked with a `ListObject` aka "table" - if your data is laid out in rows & columns, consider "format as table" and then you don't need to work out what the `Range` is, just get the table by name; the `DataBodyRange` gets you the `Range` for the table's body, `ListRows` lets you iterate the rows, etc.

Comment: @mathieu guindon where would I place that code?

Comment: I've no idea - it's very unclear where & how your current sorting is invoked. If you want to re-apply the current sorting after a click on [Save Client Data], then that's where it goes...

Comment: Oh, just realized `.Sort`  *as a property* is a member of `ListObject`. Hold on, answer on the way.

Comment: @mathieu guindon thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The little code you've shown is very redundant - by making the hard-coded `Key1` sort argument a parameter, you instantly remove the need for two of these three clones, and repurpose the third to do the job for all three.

Sorting and applying a sort, is something very easy to do when your range is a `ListObject` aka "table". Take your range, select "format as table" from the Home Ribbon. Now you never need to work out the last row ever again.

Also, if the `wss(w)` sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, there's no reason to dereference it from the `Worksheets` collection - just use its *code name* identifier (you can change it by selecting the sheet in the *Project Explorer* / Ctrl+R, then changing its `(Name)` property in the *Properties* toolwindow / F4) - then you can do `TheSheetName.Range("whatever")`. Or better - since that code only ever needs to work on a specific sheet, *put it in that sheet's code-behind*, and use `Me` to refer to the `Worksheet` instance:

```
Public Sub ApplySortOrder(Optional ByVal sortColumn As String = vbNullString)

    With Me.ListObjects(1)

        Dim sortColumnRange As Range
        If sortColumn <> vbNullString Then
            'assumes sortColumn is an existing column header
            Set sortColumnRange = .ListColumns(sortColumn).DataBodyRange
        End If
        With .Sort
            If Not sortColumnRange Is Nothing Then
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add sortColumnRange
            End If
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Now, assuming I got the assumed column headings right, the code you have that's calling `depositbalance` can look like this:

```
TheSheetName.ApplySortOrder "DepositBalance"
```

Sorting by `contactdate` would be this:

```
TheSheetName.ApplySortOrder "ContactDate"
```

Sorting by `creditbalance`:

```
TheSheetName.ApplySortOrder "CreditBalance"
```

And if you want to re-apply the current sorting:

```
TheSheetName.ApplySortOrder
```

And the day you need to sort by something else, you can just do:

```
TheSheetName.ApplySortOrder "ThatFancyNewColumn"
```

And be done with it, without needing to copy-paste yet another procedure.

You could even declare a `Public Enum` for the valid columns...

```
Public Enum SortingColumn
    Current = 0
    CreditBalance = 97
    DepositBalance = 68
    ContactDate = 2
End Enum
```

Then change the signature to accept a `SortingColumn` parameter:

```
Public Sub ApplySortOrder(Optional ByVal sortColumn As SortingColumn = Current)

    With Me.ListObjects(1)

        Dim sortColumnRange As Range
        If sortColumn <> Current Then
            'assumes sortColumn is an existing column header
            Set sortColumnRange = .ListColumns(sortColumn).DataBodyRange
        End If
        With .Sort
            If Not sortColumnRange Is Nothing Then
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add sortColumnRange
            End If
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Or even better, leave out the explicit enum values, and map each value to a string column name - then write a function that gets you the `ListColumn.Index` for it, so the user can't rename the headings, but they can still move these 90-something columns as they please. ...but that's for another post I guess.

Comment: @Jose my pleasure! I've added something to address the fact that column names are "magic strings" in the code, prone to typos - with an enum you get intellisense for it, compiler-enforced with `Option Explicit` =)